# Function to get different variable value

Tags: java

The monthly repayment of a bank housing loan of fixed interest rate is calculated using the simple amortization schedule formula.

A = P. r(1+r)^n / ((1+r)^n)-1

Where:
    A is periodic amortization payment
    P is the principal amount borrowed
    r is the percentage rate per period divided by 100
    n is the number of payments

I was able to calculate A but now i'm trying to find easy way to calculate   n

I remember i read it somewhere , if we use certain function, we can get the n value without change the formula, any ideas

Comment: The function is `B = A - C`, where `A` and `C` are inputs.  This is just basic algebra, but do you have a specific Java question?

Comment: This is simple way to do , but my formula is complicated and  consist of "power of" and other mathematical symbol. if its simple as B = A -C i can do it easily.

Comment: Then show us the exact formula you actually have.  Your current question caused several people to speculate below about what you really want.

Answer (score 2):

Using basic algebra, you can solve for b:

```
A = B +C // subtract C from both sides of the equation:
A - C = B // Flip the sides, for ease of reading:
B = A - C
```

This formula can, of course, be represented as a Java function:

```
public static int solveForB(int a, int c) {
    return a - c;
}
```